# How can I throw a custom error from \newcommand

Tags: macros

I'd like to write a command that checks the given arguments and throws an error if they are not in a range.

I'm imagining this would look something like this:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\wb}[2][]{\ifthenelse{{#2} > 0 \AND {#2} < 7}
    {\includegraphics[{#1}]{wong-baker/{#2}.eps}}}
    {%throw error here}
}
```

How can I check parameters in newcommand?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\PackageError{mypackage}{dont do that}{extra help}
```

see section 4.9 of `texdoc clsguide`

Comment: Does this also work for a quick command which is not inside any package?

Comment: @ipavlic yes you can put anything you like in the `mypackage` argument it doesn't have to be really the name of a package.

Comment: @ipavlic there is also the `\GenericError` macro, which is used by `\PackageError` internally.