# macro only for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have a macro written as `\newcommand` which contains a complete new tikz-environment.

How could one make a macro out of this that only contains the content of the tikz-environment, so that if one wants to have this drawing multiple times, it is drawn in one single tikz-environment?

I know I could simply strip the declaration of the tikz-environment in my macro, but that would let me use the macro outside a tikz-environment too.

Examples:

I have a macro similar to the following one:

```tex
\newcommand{\myTikzMacro}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I could use the macro multiple times after each other like this:

```tex
\myTikzMacro \\
\myTikzMacro \\
```

But then multiple tikz-environments would be used. To avoid that I'd be able to make this macro:

```tex
\newcommand{\myTikzMacro2}{
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,0);
```

And use it as followed:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myTikzMacro2
  \myTikzMacro2
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this would enable me to use the macro outside a `tikzpicture` environment too which I'd like to avoid too.

Is there a way to declare macros only available/visible within tikzpicture environments? (maybe with pgfkeys)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what should happen if you use the macro outside of a `tikz` environment? Just nothing? Then I have to ask _why_. Do you expect the macro to pop out at random places?

Comment: In that case I'd like the macro just not defined (latex would then error, that that macro is unknown). That's the reason why I thought of declaring the macro as a pgfkeys macro, but I don't quite know how to do that

Comment: But you would get the error anyway (undefined `\draw`). You might be interested in [How can I check if the current code is inside a tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46596/82917).

Comment: Looks like a way to get around my issue. Do you know how I'd be able to throw an Error like `Error: Macro ... is not defined` (outsite tikzpicture)?

Comment: Just found `\PackageError{mypackage}{dont do that}{extra help}` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183948/206293    Thanks @campa. Would you like to write an Answer so that I can mark it as solution?

Comment: `\PackageError` is meaningful if you are writing a package. Is that the case?

Comment: Not really up to now, but if I'm the only user it suffices to indicate an Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How can I check if the current code is inside a tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46596/82917) `tikz` provides the macro

```
\tikzifinpicture{true branch}{false branch}
```

for testing whether one is in a `tikzpicture`; the comments in its definition seem however to throw some doubts on its correctness. (I believe it might fail in nested pictures.) Assuming that it works in most simple cases you can define

```
\newcommand*{\myTikzPicture}
{\tikzifinpicture
    {%
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
     \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,0);
    }%
    {%
     \GenericError{}{Unallowed command}
             {\string\myTikzPicture\space can be used only inside a tikz picture.}{}%
    }%
}
```

I used here `\GenericError`. If the command will go into a custom package, using `\PackageError` will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find a documentation of `\GenericError` so that I can look up what't the use of the fist parameter?

Comment: @atticus `texdoc source2e`. Probably also the LaTeX companion but I can't check now. Laziest way (that's how I did): type four random but distinguishable texts and play until you understand how they work `:-)`

Comment: Thanks. They say the first one is for `contination`. Don't know what that means, but if it works like your example with an empty parameter `{}`...